# How to "convince" the other nation to not enslave demi-human

Tags: politics, fantasy-races, races, slavery, diplomacy

The Main Character is the leader of a nation of demi-humans:

[image: A set of demi-humans]

**Edit:** It seems this is not what the Asker intended. A more accurate picture is this:

[image: girl is cat maid cosplay]

Although the rest of the world is mostly in late 1700s to early 1800s, the Main Character has knowledges from the mid-21st century and are able to tech-up the nation with interwar--between WWI and WWII technology. Although the demi-human citizens are very nationalistic after unifying into a single nation and defeating human incursions (because humans discriminates against them for religious reason). The nation cannot wage wars as of this moment due to economic problems. The government needs to focus on building economy instead of military--kind of like China during the 80s and 90s. The nation is also building diplomatic relationships around--the nation needs more resources and trade partners while the human nations want some of MC's nation's resources and most importantly, tech. Quite a lot of nations have banned slavery, but acceptance of demi-human slavery still varies. A small nation with quite a bit of oil reserve is seeking to build relationship with MC's nation, knowing full well that MC's nation lacks oil and how important oil is for industrialization. And this nation also enslaves demi-human in its territory and doesn't subscribe to the more modern version of the religion where scripts supporting the discrimination against demi-human has been deleted. A war against such nation would not only drain national coffers, but also draw the ire of surrounding nations and seriously affect trade. So what kind of political move (open or discreet) can be done to subvert the slaving culture within that country's citizens and free the demi-humans?

Comment: How do they looked like? In my country we ban certain pets.

Comment: If you're asking about a political move you're probably asking about a story element rather than building a fictional world.

Comment: @user6760 They look like those catgirls--humans with animal ears and tails. It is more like japanese anime than western furry.

Comment: @FaitoDayo Gosh I was way off with the picture. How the Heck are they going to survive in the wilderness -- if they are small Japanese teenagers with cardboard triangles hot-glue-gunned to the top of their head?

Comment: They do not survive in the wild. They have villages, towns, and cities. Some of them have just discovered and started to utilize steam power.

Comment: @FaitoDayo Hmm. . .  then my answer is bunk. I have put a more accurate picture. In the future you should focus on the key terms in your question. In this case "demi-human". The question is about demi-humans so please  say what a demi-human is in your world. I had to guess and I was dead wrong!

Answer (score 3):

### Introduce modern economic theories.

[Outsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsourcing). [Franchising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchising). [Gig working](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gig_worker). [Return on investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment). [Total cost of ownership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_cost_of_ownership). And especially the [sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost).

The thing about [chattel slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery#Chattel_slavery) is that it often makes no sense in economic terms. People might believe that their slaves are a *valuable property*, but they might actually be a *liability* to the plantation if the true costs are added up. More profitable to switch to [wage slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_slavery), when the total *cost of ownership* is calculated. But the *sunk cost fallacy* means that plantation owners would loathe to admit that -- in their mind, manumission makes them poorer because they paid for the slaves.

As a first step, transition from chattel slavery to a system like wage slavery. This increases the freedom of the ex-slaves, but it might actually hurt them economically, and increase the profits of the owners-turned-employers. People from the disadvantaged groups are unable to find jobs beyond almost-starvation wages, yet their *employer* is not responsible for them as an *owner* would be. They can be fired in the off-season or when they get sick, for instance, and re-hired again when they are needed and able to work.

Next, have charities help them with donations, e.g. to send the children to school and for retirement homes. That means *your* economy subsidizes the workforce in the oil nations. But in a decade or two, the children will be educated enough to emigrate and work elsewhere, and they will have been **technically free** long enough that it can't be taken back easily.

This won't work immediately, but the charities could take on isolated hardship cases immediately.

The key to make this happen is to get the slave owners calculate the true numbers of their accounts, basing the value of a slave not on *what they once paid* but on *what they cost to maintain and what they earn.* If you are on sufficiently good terms with the government, have *your* advisors talk to *their* advisors about ways to make tax collection more efficient. Ways which involve modern accounting. If not, have *"your"* "independent" tax advisors talk to *"their"* merchants about tax avoidance strategies. When *their* government advisors wonder why revenue plummets, suggest a solution which, again, involves modern accounting. If all else fails, require foreign merchants on your soil to use modern accounting.

Comment: You mean like the Jim Crow laws?

Comment: Wage slavery is an idea, but I don't understand your first paragraph. It sounds like you are implying something.

Comment: @Daron, the third paragraph was supposed to make that clear. I'll expand.

Comment: @FaitoDayo, that and other discrimination.

Comment: @o.m. Cool. I didn't pick up that the first paragraph is a summary of the later ones.

Comment: @o.m. And "If not, have "your" mercenary tax advisors talk to "their" merchants about tax avoidance strategies." sounds like a euphamism for hiring goons to intimidate their merchants.

Comment: @Daron, I meant that the tax advisors pretend to be in it for personal profit, not on a mission for a foreign government. Edited. I mean *"I'll help you show the king's tax collectors that you actually made* no profit at all *this year. Piece of cake. Their depreciation rules are terribly unsystematic."*

Answer (score 3):

**Accept all Immigrants**

The MC offers to accept all slaves that flee across the border. Anyone who escapes is given protection. This puts pressure on the neighboring countries to treat their demi-humans well.

This would create a refugee crisis if the slaves were human. You need to find homes and jobs for the immigrants, and your cities might be too small to fit them all.

This is not a problem for demi-humans. Those guys don't need a city -- they are happy to live in the wilderness. Or at least demi-happy. It is better than being enslaved.

You see these demi-humans have keener eyes, thicker fur, sharper claws, or longer legs than normal people. Even with no experience most demi-humans are self-sufficient in the right type of wilderness.

The great thing about the MC's nation -- it is 80% unfarmable wilderness. Think dense forests, rugged mountains, lakes, coral reefs, and other places it is hard to build a city.

Demi-humans have smaller and fewer cities than regular humans. This comes from their animalistic nature. The centaurs get anxious if they cannot see the horizon. The crab people like to be underwater. The ape people need to climb trees. The wolf people feel the urge to chase down live prey. The tiger people and bear people are half solitary animal, so living in a metropolis is not for them.

Permanent residents of the cities include pure humans, ape people, wolf people, lion people, songbird people, ant people, hyaena people, deer people. Any animal that lives in large groups already.

The others live in the surrounding wilderness and commute to the city when necessary.

Comment: You mean making allegory to the freedom railway to Canada before the US Civil war?

Comment: @FaitoDayo I am not familiar with the Freedom Railway. But we should expect this policy to be at least as effective (was it effective?) since it puts less pressure on the state to accept demihuman immigrants.

Comment: I upvoted as I like this but you are asking to be raided, you have not established why the Other nations cannot just conquer the MC's nation to get the fancy new toys.

Comment: @zoboso That's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

1. Support abolitionist political movements. If not with money then maybe personnel?
2. Get former slaves to print their stories to to raise awareness and support for the absolutionist movement.
3. Suggest an alternative source of better slaves. This worked for the  Native American slave trade. Abolitionist  Who sought to  Rescue native Americans from the slave trade pointed out  That  Africans made far better slaves.  ( Immediately this is not the most ethical of solutions,  But if you're desperate or simply don't care then there you go).
4. Persuade the nations that have outlawed slavery that they have a moral responsibility to put pressure on those  Nations that still has slaves.
5. Even if you're a country is economically impoverished it doesn't mean doesn't have resources even if those resources are untapped.  Offer things like minerals or mining rights to countries  Who will take a stand with you against slavery.

Answer (score 2):

**Get them better slaves.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_among_Native_Americans_in_the_United_States

> The slave trade of Native Americans lasted until around 1730. It gave
> rise to a series of devastating wars among the tribes, including the
> Yamasee War. The Indian Wars of the early 18th century, combined with
> the increasing importation of African slaves, effectively ended the
> Native American slave trade by 1750. Colonists found that Native
> American slaves could easily escape, as they knew the country. The
> wars cost the lives of numerous colonial slave traders and disrupted
> their early societies. The remaining Native American groups banded
> together to face the Europeans from a position of strength.

For American colonists, enslaving Amerinds had one advantage: the Amerinds were there.  Slave Amerinds had disadvantages as noted and you can find more written about this as well.  When inexpensive African slaves became more widely available, slavery of Amerinds decreased and then stopped, having been supplanted.

You could make this work for your demihumans.  Perhaps some of the same disadvantages as regards slavery of Amerinds apply to demihumans.  Certainly persons who wish to use their slaves as sexual partners (which is pretty much every male with slaves) would struggle with some demihumans.  Although maybe not?  Not sure how some of these demihumans are set up.

---

I do not want to see downvotes because "slavery is bad!".  OK; Daron you can.  But I do not like slavery and despite the fact that they are fictional, ideas about making these slave owners see the light of justice and then sing kumbayah with their former demihuman slaves (especially slave Ariel with her sweet voice!) makes my heart feel warm and fuzzy.  In case those ideas do not work for the story at hand, alternate slaves is an alternate idea.

Comment: But it doesn't really solve the problem. The goal of the administration is to subvert the culture of slaving demi-human. Even if the locals feel "demi-human is not good for slaving" they will still be mistreated.

Comment: The stated problem is "How to "convince" the other nation to not enslave demi-human".  Having them love demihumans as equals is just one solution.  This idea is another.  Or you could have assassins kill any demihuman slaves so slaveowners would quit wasting their money on them.  You get to pick which one fits your story best.

Comment: It is not about "telling them to love demi-human". After civil war, heavy discrimination against African-Americans still exist in Southern US and the conditions of the "freed" blacks did not improve much. I want the MC to ensure that, after that target nation declared banning of slavery, the ex-slaves will be actually better

Comment: @FaitoDayo This is the second answer that fails because of a reason you have in your head -- you want to end all discrimination and not just slavery -- but you did not put in the question. Please keep this in mind when writing future questions.

Comment: @FaitoDayo Oh and please do not modify your question after answers have been posted. It is okay to add extra stuff using **Edit:** but if you delete stuff it confuses people when answers refer to part of the question that no longer exists.

Comment: @FaitoDayo what your asking for is impossible.  You can change laws sure but not hearts. Maybe if you had a generation or 2 but not right away.